# Number of a self avoiding cycles in 2D with a given area

Tags: combinatorics, probability-theory, statistical-mechanics

Consider a two dimensional square lattice and let $C_n$ be the number of self avoiding cycles (i.e., a self avoiding walk that starts at the origin and terminates at the origin) such that the number of vertices ``inside'' the cycle is $n$.

Does $C_n$ grow exponentially with n?

More precisely, by ``number of vertices inside the cycle'', we mean the number of vertices which are in the set whose boundary is the cycle and we do not count the vertices belonging to the cycle itself.

**Comment.** If $C_n$ was the number of cycles having $n$ vertices, the behaviour of $C_n$ would be known to be as $\sim \mu^n$, where $\mu$ is a constant depending only on the lattice, known as *connective constant*. This comes from a subadditive argument.

Comment: Can you explain "number of vertices inside the cycle"? Do you mean the length of the cycle (number of steps), or the number of lattice points in the region bounded by the cycle? If the latter, then do you count lattice points on the boundary as well?

Comment: I have answered in the text. Please see my edit. Thanks for your question.